# how to write asp.net to create a file in sharepoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

After giving up java script, I'm writing the asp.net to make a popup, and once the user finish wrting the content and title, it will make a .aspx file and upload to documentary library.

But how can I do that? I googled but not many materials on that!

Anyone can help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468469/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-a-document-library-in-sharepoint

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a file in sharepoint using asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689474/how-to-create-a-file-in-sharepoint-using-asp-net)